# Retrying failed custom token transaction with '@solana/web3.js'

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I want to send my deployed token other than sol using solana web3.js. My code works most of the time but sometimes the transaction fails.

I put a while loop so that when the transaction fails the client retries it with the sendRawTransaction function. The problem is that when it fails the first time it always fails after it.

```js
        const provider = await this.getProvider();

        const publicKey = new web3.PublicKey(this.wallet);
        const toPublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(
            "the public key to send"
        );
        const mint = new web3.PublicKey(
            "my token adress"
        );

        const connection = await new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
        const { signTransaction } = useWallet();

        const fromTokenAccount = await this.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            publicKey,
            mint,
            publicKey,
            signTransaction
        )
        });

        const toTokenAccount = await this.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            publicKey,
            mint,
            toPublicKey,
            signTransaction
        );

        const transferInstruction = await this.createTransferInstruction(
            fromTokenAccount.address, // source
            toTokenAccount.address, // dest
            publicKey,
            amount,
            [],
            TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        );

        const transaction = new Transaction().add(transferInstruction);

        var blockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');
        transaction.feePayer = await publicKey;
        console.log(blockHash.blockhash)
        transaction.recentBlockhash = blockHash.blockhash;


        //  const provider = await this.getProvider();
        const signed = await provider.signTransaction(transaction);
        
        window.createEvent('openPopup', {
            text: 'Your transaction is being validated by the Solana blockchain.',
            loading: 30, 
            show: true
        })
        var nbRetry = 0;
        while(true){
        const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signed.serialize())
            
        this.post(`verifyTransaction`, {
            signature,
        })
        .then(() => {
            window.location.assign('/transaction_success')
        })
        .catch(async (error) => {
            if (error.response.status === 403) {
                if (nbRetry > 5){
                window.createEvent('openPopup', {
                    show: true,
                    image: 'error.png',
                    text: 'The transaction failed.',
                    reload: true
                })} else nbRetry++;


                
            }}
        })
```

Comment: maybe devnet was down on that day?